# Challenging problem: Find $a$ where $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)\ln(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> What is the value of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ that makes the following integral true
> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)\ln(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=0\,?$$

This question was proposed by my friend *Khalef Ruhemi* and I have no idea how to approach it but all I tried is setting $x=\tan\theta$ and I don't know how to continue after that. Also I noticed that the integrand is an even function and again I don't know how to make use of this fact. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: With CAS,looks like: $a=\frac{e^{-\gamma }}{2}$

Comment: @Mariusz WA gives a non-zero result for such $a$ (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+from+0+to+inf+of+%28cos%28%28e%5E%28gamma%29x%29%2F2%29ln%281%2Bx%5E%282%29%29%29%2F%28%5Csqrt%281%2Bx%5E%282%29%29%29)

Comment: @LuisSierra. $$a=\frac{e^{-\gamma }}{2}$$ and try again.

Comment: @Luis Sierra you forgot the negative sign.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad, sorry :p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider
$$\underbrace{\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(ax\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^b}\:dx}_{x=\frac{t}{a}}=a^{2b-1}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{\left(a^2+t^2\right)^b}\:dt$$
Now use the following identity that can be found [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).
$$K_v\left(z\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(v+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(2z\right)^v}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int _0^{\infty \:}\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{\left(z^2+t^2\right)^{v+\frac{1}{2}}} dt$$
This leads to
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(ax\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^b}\:dx=a^{2b-1}K_{b-\frac{1}{2}}\left(a\right)\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\Gamma \left(b\right)\left(2a\right)^{b-\frac{1}{2}}}$$
This means that
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(ax\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\:dx=-\lim _{b\to \frac{1}{2}}\frac{\partial }{\partial b}a^{2b-1}K_{b-\frac{1}{2}}\left(a\right)\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\Gamma \left(b\right)\left(2a\right)^{b-\frac{1}{2}}}$$
Using mathematica to complete the calculations we are left with
$$K_0\left(a\right)\left(-\ln \left(a\right)+\ln \left(2\right)+\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)-K^{\left(1,0\right)}_0\left(a\right)$$

Now you can check [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/20/01/01/0003/) that
$$K^{\left(1,0\right)}_0\left(a\right)=0$$
Proof provided below.

Meaning overall
$$=K_0\left(a\right)\left(-\ln \left(a\right)+\ln \left(2\right)-\gamma -2\ln \left(2\right)\right)$$
$$\boxed{\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(ax\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\:dx=-K_0\left(a\right)\left(\ln \left(a\right)+\gamma +\ln \left(2\right)\right)}$$
Which agrees with the results proposed above.

Now answering the main point,
$$-K_0\left(a\right)\left(\ln \left(a\right)+\gamma +\ln \left(2\right)\right)=0$$
$$\ln \left(2a\right)+\gamma =0$$
$$2a=e^{-\gamma }$$

We find that $\displaystyle a=\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{2}$

And so by plugging it in we can immediately see
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(\frac{e^{-\gamma }}{2}x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\:dx=-K_0\left(\frac{e^{-\gamma }}{2}\right)\left(-\gamma -\ln \left(2\right)+\gamma +\ln \left(2\right)\right)=0$$

---

### Proof of tools used.

> $$K^{\left(1,0\right)}_0\left(a\right)=0$$

$$K_v\left(a\right)=\int _0^{\infty }e^{-a\cosh \left(t\right)}\cosh \left(vt\right)\:dt$$
Differentiating with respect to $v$ gives us
$$K_v^{\left(1,0\right)}\left(a\right)=\int _0^{\infty }te^{-a\cosh \left(t\right)}\sinh \left(vt\right)\:dt$$
Now let $v=0$
$$K_0^{\left(1,0\right)}\left(a\right)=\int _0^{\infty }te^{-a\cosh \left(t\right)}\sinh \left(0\right)\:dt=0$$

> $\displaystyle K_v\left(a\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(v+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(2a\right)^v}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{\left(a^2+t^2\right)^{v+\frac{1}{2}}}\:dt=\int _0^{\infty }e^{-a\cosh \left(t\right)}\cosh \left(vt\right)\:dt$

First consider
$$I\left(a\right)=\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(ax\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^v}\:dx$$

Well make use of the following gamma function representation $$\Gamma(v)={\left(1+x^{2}\right)}^{v}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(1+x^{2}\right)u} u^{v-1}du$$
Multiply $I\left(a\right)$ by $\Gamma(v)$
$$\Gamma(v)I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(ax)\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\left(1+x^{2}\right)u} u^{v-1}dudx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{v-1}e^{-u}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}u}\cos(ax)dxdu=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{{\pi}}\underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{v-\frac{2}{2}}e^{-u-\frac{a^{2}}{4u}}du}_{u=\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)e^t}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{1}{\Gamma(v)}{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}^{v-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}e^{\left(v-\frac{1}{2}\right)t} dt$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(v)}{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)}^{v-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}\cosh{\left(\left(v-\frac{1}{2}\right)t\right)} dt$$
$$\frac{\Gamma \left(v\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}\:\left(\frac{2}{a}\right)^{v-\frac{1}{2}}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(ax\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^v}\:dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-a\cosh(t)}\cosh{\left(\left(v-\frac{1}{2}\right)t\right)} dt$$
$$\frac{\Gamma \left(v+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}\:\left(\frac{2}{a}\right)^v\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\cos \left(ax\right)}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{v+\frac{1}{2}}}\:dx=\int _0^{\infty }e^{-a\cosh \left(t\right)}\cosh \left(vt\right)\:dt$$

Comment: Very nice thank you all steps are pretty clear (+1) , but solution would be nicer if you can prove that  $K^{\left(1,0\right)}_0\left(a\right)=0$. Relying on ready results is not useful for the readers.

Comment: You are right but see that i factored the - sign from the whole expression.
$$K_0\left(a\right)\left(-\ln \left(a\right)+\ln \left(2\right)+\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)=K_0\left(a\right)\left(-\ln \left(a\right)+\ln \left(2\right)-\gamma -2\ln \left(2\right)\right)=K_0\left(a\right)\left(-\ln \left(a\right)-\gamma \:-\ln \left(2\right)\right)$$

Comment: @AliShather provided a simple proof, hopefully it is enough.

Comment: So your solution will be complete if you can prove  $$K_v\left(a\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(v+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(2a\right)^v}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int _0^{\infty \:}\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{\left(a^2+t^2\right)^{v+\frac{1}{2}}} dt=\int _0^{\infty }e^{-a\cosh \left(t\right)}\cosh \left(vt\right)\:dt$$

Comment: @AliShather ok let me know if there are steps that need clarification.

Comment: Perfect. your solution is complete now. Thanks again. You should publish this solution.

Comment: Thank you for the good question .

Answer (score 6):

The integral equals
$$
K_0(a) (\gamma+\log(2)+\log(a)) \tag{*}
$$
(where [$K_0(a)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10) is a modified Bessel function, assume $a>0$, $a<0$ follows by symmetry), which can be shown by integration under the integral sign together with $K_0'(a)=-K_1(a)$.

Since Bessel K's have no zeros, we can equate the bracket in (*) to zero and get

> $$
> a=\pm\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{2}\approx\pm 0.28073\,,
> $$

which is the same as numercis suggests (see comments to question).

Comment: I didn't understand anything except your first line which is obtained by mathematica. You said it can be sown using integration under the integral sign, can we give more details? and can you explain how  $K_0'(a)=-K_1(a)$? everything is unclear I wonder why? you have unlimited space to type.Lets wait for other solutions.

Comment: Integration under the integral sign is illegitimate here since attempting to do so results in a divergent integral.

Comment: Answer is $\displaystyle\color{red}{\Large -}\mathrm{K}_{0}\left(\left\vert a\right\vert\right) \left[\gamma + \log\left(2\right) + \log\left(\left\vert a\right\vert\right)\right]$. See the ${\tt minus\ sign}$.

Answer (score 3):

Solution due to *Khalef Ruhemi* without using any kind of software:

Define

$$f(p,q)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(qx)}{(1+x^2)^p}dx,\quad p>0, q\ne0$$

By $$\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^p}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^\infty y^{p-1}e^{-(1+x^2)y}dy$$

We  have

$$f(p,q)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^\infty y^{p-1} e^{-y}\underbrace{\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2y}\cos(qx) dx\right)}_{x^2y=t^2}dy$$

$$=\frac{1}{\Gamma(p)}\int_0^\infty y^{p-\frac32} e^{-y}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\cos\left(\frac{qt}{\sqrt{y}}\right)dt\right)dy$$

$$=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\Gamma(p)}\int_0^\infty y^{p-\frac32} e^{-(y+\frac{q^2}{4y})}dy\tag1$$

$$\overset{\frac{q^2}{4y}=x}{=}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\Gamma(p)}\left|\frac{q}{2}\right|^{2p-1}\int_0^\infty x^{-p-\frac12}e^{-(x+\frac{q^2}{4x})}dx$$

$$=\frac{\Gamma(1-q)}{\Gamma(p)}\left|\frac{q}{2}\right|^{2p-1}\underbrace{\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\Gamma(1-p)}\int_0^\infty x^{-p-\frac12}e^{-(x+\frac{q^2}{4x})}dx\right)}_{=f(1-p,q)\ \text{by} (1)}$$

Thus,

$$f(p,q)=\frac{\Gamma(1-q)}{\Gamma(p)}\left|\frac{q}{2}\right|^{2p-1}f(1-p,q)$$

or,

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(qx)}{(1+x^2)^p}dx=\frac{\Gamma(1-q)}{\Gamma(p)}\left|\frac{q}{2}\right|^{2p-1}\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(qx)}{(1+x^2)^{1-p}}dx,\quad 0<p<1\tag2$$

Note that $0<p<1$ follows from the fact that $p>0$ and $1-p>0$.

Next, differentiate both sides of $(2)$ with respect to $p$ then let $p\to 1/2$ we have

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(qx)\ln(1+x^2)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx=-\ln|2qe^{\gamma}|\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(qx)}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx$$

Finally, since the LHS integral is equal to zero, we have

$$\ln|2qe^{\gamma}|=0\Longrightarrow q=\pm\frac12e^{-\gamma}.$$